# Function mcrypt_decrypt() only working for short strings

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, encryption

I'm currently encrypting in iOS and decrypting in PHP.  It works fine if the string I'm encrypting/decrypting is less than 16 characters in length.

iOS code to encrypt:

```
    - (NSData *)AES128Encrypt:(NSData *)this
{
    // ‘key’ should be 16 bytes for AES128
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
    NSString *key = @"1234567890123456";
    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [this length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That’s why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode | kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [this bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted );
    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}
```

PHP code to decrypt:

```
function decryptThis($key, $pass)
{

    $base64encoded_ciphertext = $pass;

    $res_non = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $base64encoded_ciphertext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

    $decrypted = $res_non;
    $dec_s2 = strlen($decrypted);

    $padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s2-1]);
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);

    return  $decrypted;
}
```

If the string decrypted is longer than 16 characters PHP only returns *@"\n\n"*. However, short strings like '*what*' gets decrypted correctly and PHP returns *@"what\n\n"*.  What's going on here? I'd like to be able to decrypt strings 500+ characters long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ECB mode in iOS and CBC on PHP. PHP furthermore does not detect incorrect paddings, so if the last byte of the (incorrect) padded plaintext has a high value it will probably generate an empty string.

Comment: in iOS, the CCCrypt function only accepts 2 options: kCCOptionECBMode and kCCOptionPKCS7Padding. Removing the ECB option apparently encrypts it in CBC. I wanted to use CBC because I read it would hold longer strings.

Comment: @GabCas CBC mode *should* be used for strings, as ECB mode is not safe to use for strings. Both can hold an infinite amount of data (possibly limited by security considerations of the underlying block cipher). The secure use of CBC mandates a random IV, which can be send in plain with the ciphertext.